# How to install previous releases of wix toolset

Tags: wix

I am sorry for this stupid question, but I really need to install version 3.9 of the Wix Toolset. I can only find version 3.10 and 3.11. There is a link on the website to download older archives (also for 3.9rc2), but in this 1.2Gb file I cannot find an installer.

Please do not tell me to install the latest version, I have my own reasons for 3.9 that goes beyond the scope of this question. Any help is truely appreciated.

Comment: If it helps to understand: The "download archive" link is for the last state of the project on the now archive-only CodePlex site. It was created by CodePlex when it shut down, not by the WiX Toolset maintainers. So, the links on the WiX website are effectively dead. Sorry, I don't know where 3.9 binaries or installers are either.

Comment: I hope you saved the downloaded archive. Find releaseList.json to identify the location of the file you want, extract it and rename it to the indicated filename.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a need to get the old wix38.exe installer for legacy project maintenance, and it was a pain. Tom Blodget's comment above was the key on how to find the required file from the CodePlex archive.

Because there are likely to be other people in the future who require access to these things, I've created a github repository https://github.com/CasaDeRobison/wixtoolset-codeplex that includes the state of the git repository from the CodePlex archive and also makes available the various files from those releases at https://github.com/CasaDeRobison/wixtoolset-codeplex/tree/master/archived-stable-versions

Hopefully others will find this useful as well so that we don't all have to collectively puzzle this out if we have a need for this older software.

Comment: Is it possible to use these to do a silent install? I need to install version 3.8 or earlier, for Visual Studio 2008 using completely silent install.

Answer (score 1):

I should leave this for the WiX guys to answer, but maybe you are very busy and just need to test something?

Building it yourself from the sources isn't an option is it? https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases (towards the bottom, click the blue image - it says "Show 5 other tags" here). Sounds painful to work that out...

The 3.9 binaries seem to be here (looks like R1): https://github.com/continuoustests/ContinuousTests/tree/master/Installer/ContinuousTests.WixInstaller/wix39-binaries, but not as an installer file. Maybe you just need to test something quickly? If so, obviously please accept your own risk here, I am not sure what these files really are.

I hope I haven't linked to something that is problematic, just delete the whole answer if this should be the case (i.e the binaries pointed to should not ever be used - for some reason, etc...).